# How can I force IE10/9 into both Compatibility View and IE8 Document Mode?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10, x-ua-compatible

I am working on a site that uses an outdated JavaScript framework (Backbase 3). Previously, we forced the document into Quirks Mode for all versions of IE, but the outdated box model rendering is no longer tenable.

For IE9 and IE10, our framework *must* use Compatibility View to function. If I deviate from Quirks mode, I have found (via the IE Developer Tool) that the site functions well in IE9/10 with a Document Mode of "IE8 standards". However, when in Compatibility View, IE9/10 shifts by default into a Document Mode of "IE7 standards" and I cannot seem to get it into "IE8 standards" by any means other than the Developer Tool.

I have tried every DOCTYPE and no DOCTYPE; I have tried the X-UA-Compatible meta tag (placed first in the header) with IE=8, IE=EmulateIE8, and most every other value. Nothing seems to work.

Put simply, once IE9/10 has been switched to Compatibility View, is there any way to also force it into a Document Mode of "Internet Explorer 8 standards"?

ps. Yes, I know the *best* thing would be to stop using this outdated framework, but my hands are tied at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I used `<!DOCTYPE html>` in the starting of the document and used

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" >
```

after the `<head>`.
Then i cleared the cache of the browser, reopen the internet explorer and it is working fine.